# Conditional Formatting IF value in col A is repeated AND is not the MAX (evaluating only the rows with repeats) of col B

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet with many columns paired together: a string and a value. I have been able conditionally to highlight repeated strings, which is half of what I am trying to do.

The other half is trying to highlight the value column of repeated strings if they are not the MAX value of the respective repeats. I have tried many things and have gotten close, but currently am not able to get the data in the value columns to consider all value columns.

I will link to a demo sheet using RPG style class/rank relationships as an example. Turning off the green conditional highlighting (which is wrong) will reveal how it should be working (non-conditional formatting).

[Test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LXGoctsHomZktwRvJM8FQGKR4CXi8_TyeTnbnLsn_x4/edit?usp=sharing)  P.S. there is a lot of junk on the bottom: Various things I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

For Group 1 for example you can use something like the following as your conditional formatting rule:

```
=and(countif($A$3:$A$8,A3)>1,B3<> MAXIFS($B$3:$B$8,$A$3:$A$8,A3))
```

Comment: That gets me part of the way there, but I need it to consider both groups together.  There will actually be 5 groups when completed.  Is this possible or will I need to look into attaching a script?  - thanks again.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If there is only one Monk in group 1 and one Monk in group 2, both strings (monk) should highlight and the lower corresponding value (rank) should highlight. In other words, highlighting should occur across groups.